# measuring uncertainty in matlabs svmclassify

Tags: matlab, svm, uncertainty

I'm doing contextual object recognition and I need a prior for my observations. e.g. this space was labeled "dog", what's the probability that it was labeled correctly? Do you know if matlabs svmclassify has an argument to return this level of certainty with it's classification?

If not, matlabs svm has the following structures in it:

```
SVM = 
      SupportVectors: [11x124 single]
               Alpha: [11x1 double]
                Bias: 0.0915
      KernelFunction: @linear_kernel
  KernelFunctionArgs: {}
          GroupNames: {11x1 cell}
SupportVectorIndices: [11x1 double]
           ScaleData: [1x1 struct]
       FigureHandles: []
```

Can you think of any ways to compute a good measure of uncertainty from these? (Which support vector to use?) Papers/articles explaining uncertainty in SVMs welcome. More in depth explanations of matlabs SVM are also welcome.

If you can't do it this way, can you think of any other libraries with SVMs that have this measure of uncertainty?

Comment: You mean posterior, right? Given the training, for a test data point the classifier should not just return best class, but a probability for each class, such that the one with the highest probability is the best.

Answer (score 5):

Salam,

Hint: I would suggest that you modify the svmclassify.m function to pass the f values of the svmdecision.m to the user. This is in addition to the outputclass.

To access svmclassify.m, just type the following in the Matlab command line:

```
 open svmclassify
```

I found that svmdecision.m (https://code.google.com/p/auc-recognition/source/browse/trunk/ALLMatlab/AucLib/DigitsOfflineNew/svmdecision.m?spec=svn260&r=260) can pass the f value; so the following may be substitude when calling the svmdecision.m in svmclassify.m:

```
[classified, f] = svmdecision(sample,svmStruct);
```

By further passing this f value to the user, the multi-class implementations such as one-vs-all may be designed with the binary classifier already built in Matlab.

f values are what you are looking for in terms of comparison of different inputs being related to their output class.

I hope this helps you to write your code and understand it! though you've probably solved your problem by now.

Answer (score 1):

I know this was posted a long time ago, but I think the author is looking for a measure of uncertainty in the output of the trained SVM, whether the output is an estimated label or an estimated probability, which are both point estimates.  One measure would be the variance of the output for the same input x.  The problem is that regular SVMs are not stochastic models, such as probabilistic/Bayesian neural nets for example. The inference with an SVM is always the same, given the same x.

I would need to check, but perhaps it would be possible to train an SVM with stochastic regularization.  Maybe some form of stochastic margin maximization, whereby during the steps of the optimization routine, input training vectors can undergo small stochastic perturbations or perhaps randomly chosen features could be dropped out.  Similarly, during testing, one could drop or modify different randomly chosen features, producing different point estimates each time.  Then, you could take the variance of the estimates, producing the measure of uncertainty.

It could be argued that, if the input x presents patterns that the model is not familiar with, the point estimates will be wildly unstable and variable.

One simple illustration can be the following: Imagine a 2d toy example, where the two classes are well separated and occupy a dense range of feature values. While a model trained on this set will generalize well to points that fall into the distribution/range of the values seen in the train data, it would be quite unstable given a test observation that sits far away from both classes, but at the same latitude, so to speak, as the separating hyperplane. Such an observations presents a challenge to the model since a tiny perturbation of one of the support vectors could cause a tiny rotation in the separating hyperplane, not significantly changing training or validation error, but potentially changing the estimate of the far-away test observation by a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Are you supplying the data and doing the training yourself?  If so, the best thing to do is to partition your data into training and test sets.  Matlab has a function for this called cvpartition.  You can use the classification results on the test data to estimate the rate of false positive and the miss rate.  For a binary classification task, those two numbers will quantify the uncertainty.  For a classification test with multiple hypotheses the best thing to do, probably, is to compile your results in a confusion matrix.

*edit. found some older code I'd used that might help a little*

```
P=cvpartition(Y,'holdout',0.20);

rbfsigma=1.41;

svmStruct=svmtrain(X(P.training,:),Y(P.training),'kernel_function','rbf','rbf_sigma',rbfsigma,'boxconstraint',0.7,'showplot','true');

C=svmclassify(svmStruct,X(P.test,:));

errRate=sum(Y(P.test)~=C)/P.TestSize
conMat=confusionmat(Y(P.test),C)
```

Comment: Great, I appreciate this suggestion. Forgive me if I'm missing something, but won't these false positive/miss rates only be single numbers? I.e. If I have 10 labelings in a picture, these rates will have to be applied to all the labelings? I would like something that says "this particular labeling is very certain, this one is less so". The uncertainty needs to be relative to the actual uncertainty of this particular labeling, not an average or aggregate. Is there any way to do this? Is there any way to get the actual score that svmclassify actually gave to this particular labeling?

Comment: And yes I am supplying the training and testing data

Comment: I see.  As far as I know SVMs aren't probabilistic per se so it may be hard to discuss uncertainty outside of evaluating the classifier on some reliable test data.  However, one thing you might be able to look at is the actual value of the objective function for the particular example you've classified.  A value close to zero would seem to suggest it's a borderline case.

Answer (score 0):

[LIBSVM](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/libsvm/), which also has a Matlab interface, has an option `-b` that makes the classification function return probability estimates. They seem to be computed following the general approach of Platt (2000), which is to perform a one-dimensional logistic regression applied to the decision values.

Platt, J. C. (2000). Probabilities for SV machines. In Smola, A. J. et al. (eds.) *Advances in large margin classifiers*. pp. 61–74. Cambridge: The MIT Press.